# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter and cant connect to SoapClient

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to web services and might be doing small mistake somewhere.I am trying to connect and use a WebService with PHP and SoapClient and getting a following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter in /www/1/html/webservices/tuev-nord-ass/soapclientconnect.php
```

WSDL link:

```
http://www.schwackenet.de/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl
```

My code:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');

$wsdl = 'http://www.schwackenet.de/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl';

$options = array('trace' => true);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, 
array( 
'user' =>               'tülsenbeck',
'password' =>           'tülsenbeck',
'corporate_group_id' => '101',
'dealer_number' =>      'INT31303',
'dms_id' =>             'A13T2D19',
'dms_image_url' =>      '', 
'dms_keepalive_url' =>  '', 
'dms_followup_url' =>   '',
)
);
//Returns list of available SOAP functions described in the WSDL for the Web service. 
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
//some parameters to send
$result = $client>Login('user','password','corporate_group_id','dealer_number','dms_id','dms_image_url','dms_keepalive_url','dms_followup_url');
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: I've been working with soap webservices for a few months now and everytime I get that error is because I forgot some parameter when calling the webservice. 
Double-Check if you're sending all the parameters that the webservice needs, even if empty.

but ill be honest, I don't know enough to spot it.

Comment: Thanks MoshMage i am checking whether i m missing any parameter but did not find anyone :(

Comment: Denken Sie ist es egal, welche Sprache für Paramnamen zu benutzen? :-) There is clearly stated in service description, that the param names are to be `user`, `password` etc.

Comment: oh, and don't forget to actually create an array of values, `$params = array('User' => '$user' ... );` and calling it with `cliente->Login($params);`

Comment: @mudasobwa i have all the parameters now correctly added please check but still its giving the same error :(

Comment: @MoshMage i already have values , please check it in my update question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You completely mess the function arguments up.

```
$options = array('trace' => true);
$params = array(
  'user' =>               'deshmukh',
  'password' =>           'deshmukh',
  'corporate_group_id' => '101',
  'dealer_number' =>      'INT31303',
  'dms_id' =>             'A13T2D19',
  'dms_image_url' =>      '', 
  'dms_keepalive_url' =>  '', 
  'dms_followup_url' =>   ''  
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);      // options!!!
$result = $client->Login($params);              // params!!!
```

Now it replies with “Zugangsdaten sind nicht gültig,” I guess you’ll go further yourself.

MfG